# Other methods to reduce if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a large array and I have too filter the array based on path and date. Here is the code I have written in order to do that but it is taking a bit too long to execute because the size of the array. Is there any other way I can do this more efficiently.

```
foreach ($posters as &$poster) {
    $stats[$poster['Identifier']] = array_filter($stats_results, function($item) use ($poster){

            $date = strtotime($item['start_date']);

            $presentation_date = strtotime($poster['Presentation_Date']);

            $expiry=strtotime($poster['Expiry_Date']);

            if($item['path'] == '/' . $poster['Identifier']){
                return 
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry );

                }
            if($item['path'] == '/' . $poster['Identifier'].'/pdf-emailed.php'){
                return 
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/' . $poster['Identifier'].'.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/DE'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/FR'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/ES'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/PT'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/IT'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/UK'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date<= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Germany/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/DE.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date<= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/France/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/FR.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Spain/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/ES.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Japan/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/JA.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Portugal/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/PT.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }

            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Italy/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/IT.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
            if($item['path'] == 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/UK.pdf'){
                return
                    ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But they all return the same thing?

Comment: look into Regular Expressions. Or alternatively `in_array()`. Anyway THAT code wont take long to executes. If you could lose noticeably performance on ifs almost every program would be slow.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array where all the test values are keys, and test for a match.

```
foreach ($posters as &$poster) {
    $stats[$poster['Identifier']] = array_filter($stats_results, function($item) use ($poster){
            $date = strtotime($item['start_date']);
            $presentation_date = strtotime($poster['Presentation_Date']);
            $expiry=strtotime($poster['Expiry_Date']);

            $test_array = array ('/' . $poster['Identifier'] => true
                                 '/' . $poster['Identifier'].'/pdf-emailed.php' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/' . $poster['Identifier'].'.pdf' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/DE' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/FR' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/ES' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/PT' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/IT' => true
                                 '/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/email_sent/UK' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Germany/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/DE.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/France/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/FR.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Spain/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/ES.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Japan/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/JA.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Portugal/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/PT.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/Italy/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/IT.pdf' => true
                                 'http://www.xyz.com/uploads/'.$poster['Identifier'].'/download/UK.pdf' => true);
            if (isset($test_array[$item['path']])) {
                return ($date >= $presentation_date && $date <= $expiry);
            }
        });
}
```

Other possibilities are to use a `switch` statement. Or, since many of your strings are very similar, you can combine them into a regular expression with alternations, and use `preg_match`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I have tried to use your approach but the script runs out memory. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Make sure you empty the array first each time in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your time. Sorry for the late replay. I was on holiday. The issue is solved by changes the server from Shared to VPS. The code executes very fast. Thanks again.